# Jackson Converter - web service is mixed camel case and underscores - can I have multipole naming strategy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I have a class:

```
class Person {

  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  // Getters and stuff
}
```

My JSON from the web service is like `'{"firstName": "Mike", "last_name": "Last"}'`

Is there a way to configure Jackson to convert without annotating each field with its format with a `JsonProperty` annotation?  This is a contrived example but my "real" web service has loads of fields.

If I use the default case, I get firstName set and lastName null, and if I get SNAKE_CASE I get the opposite.

Can I have it try both?

Here's the (kotlin) configuration for the mapper I'm using, currently last_name gets set and firstName does not:

```
@Bean
fun mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(): MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
    val jsonConverter = MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()
    val objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .modules(KotlinModule())
            .build<ObjectMapper>()
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    jsonConverter.objectMapper = objectMapper
    return jsonConverter
}
```

Comment: Are you deserializing only, or also serializing? If you are serializing back to JSON you absolutely need to annotate the fields (since the Java field is absent information on which case to use).

Comment: Assuming you are only deserializing, I imagine you can write a custom naming strategy, the delegates to SNAKE_CASE if the key contains an "_", and delegates to lowerCamelCase otherwise. There seems to be an example here (minus the delegation, but hopefully you can just construct each built-in naming strategy): https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-property-custom-naming-strategy (apologies, I'm not an expert).

Comment: I am only deserializing - I might try that when I get some time...